# Solr reports: "Connection refused" when running import

Tags: java, apache, solr

I am running a database that acts as the source for data to import into Solr. When I run the command: curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import&commit=true", the commit fails and the instance does a rollback. Can you help me to figure this out?

**Here is the exception stack:**

> ```
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter doFullImport
>     INFO: Starting Full Import
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
>     INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/dataimport params={command=full-import&commit=true} status=0 QTime=0 
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter readIndexerProperties
>     INFO: Read dataimport.properties
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 deleteAll
>     INFO: [] REMOVING ALL DOCUMENTS FROM INDEX
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onInit
>     INFO: SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits:num=1
>       commit{dir=/private/var/www/html/internsolr/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_21,version=1320251100987,generation=73,filenames=[segments_21]
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy updateCommits
>     INFO: newest commit = 1320251100987
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1 call
>     INFO: Creating a connection for entity id with URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/internshipsearch
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>     SEVERE: Exception while processing: id document : SolrInputDocument[{}]:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException:
> ```
>
> Unable to execute query: select respondentid,
>   first_name,                           last_name,
>   cmc_email_address,                           graduation_year,
>   first_major,                           additional_major,
>   sequence,                           other_major,
>   organization_name,                           organization_website,
>   organization_desc,                           industry,
>   job_title,                           department,
>   city,                           state,
>   country,                           region,
>   internship_paid,                           hourly_salary,
>   year_undertaken,                           recommend_again,
>   employer_supervisor,                           employer_phone,
>   employer_email,                           not_recommended_desc,
>   full_time_offer,                           full_time_accept,
>   attend_summer_classes,
>   summer_classes_institution,
>   summer_classes_desc,                           summer_travel,
>   summer_travel_city,                           summer_travel_state,
>   summer_travel_country,
>   summer_other_activity,
>   summer_other_activity_desc,                           how_discovered, 
>   doe_start_month,                           doe_start_day,
>   doe_end_month,                           doe_end_day             from
>   interndata Processing Document # 1
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
>           Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ```
>     ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
>
>     java.net.SocketException
>     MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
>     STACKTRACE:
>
>     java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
>
>
>     ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
>
>
>     Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
>       ... 11 more
>
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
>     SEVERE: Full Import failed:org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException:
> ```
>
> Unable to execute query: select respondentid,
>   first_name,                           last_name,
>   cmc_email_address,                           graduation_year,
>   first_major,                           additional_major,
>   sequence,                           other_major,
>   organization_name,                           organization_website,
>   organization_desc,                           industry,
>   job_title,                           department,
>   city,                           state,
>   country,                           region,
>   internship_paid,                           hourly_salary,
>   year_undertaken,                           recommend_again,
>   employer_supervisor,                           employer_phone,
>   employer_email,                           not_recommended_desc,
>   full_time_offer,                           full_time_accept,
>   attend_summer_classes,
>   summer_classes_institution,
>   summer_classes_desc,                           summer_travel,
>   summer_travel_city,                           summer_travel_state,
>   summer_travel_country,
>   summer_other_activity,
>   summer_other_activity_desc,                           how_discovered, 
>   doe_start_month,                           doe_start_day,
>   doe_end_month,                           doe_end_day             from
>   interndata Processing Document # 1
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:72)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.(JdbcDataSource.java:253)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
>             at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
>           Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:
>
> ```
>     ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
>
>     java.net.SocketException
>     MESSAGE: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>
>     STACKTRACE:
>
>     java.net.SocketException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2666)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:210)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getData(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.initQuery(SqlEntityProcessor.java:59)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextRow(SqlEntityProcessor.java:73)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:238)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:596)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
>
>
>     ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
>
>
>     Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2741)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1531)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:161)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:128)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:363)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:39)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:240)
>       ... 11 more
>
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
>     INFO: start rollback
>     Jan 27, 2012 4:02:32 PM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
>     INFO: end_rollback
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a connection error, so check the data sources in the beginning of the data-config.xml file in Solr. It's probably just something simple like a bad URL, incorrect credentials, forgot to put the DB name in the URL, etc. Make sure you can ping the DB server from the Solr server.

The datasource tag should be something like this:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
  driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://database.server.com/database-name" 
  user="user" 
  password="pass"
  name="datasource-name" />
```

And the entities in your data-config.xml should either have no datasource specified (if you only have one in the file) or should specify the name of the datasource you want to use if there are multiple.

Good luck!

Comment: My datasource is fine:   <dataSource name="internshipdata"
              type="JdbcDataSource"
              driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/internshipsearch"
              user="root"
              password="root"/>. I was able to connect using mysql from the terminal. How would I go about pinging the server from Solr?

Comment: Btw, both: Solr and MySQL are on the same server.

Comment: I was able to connect and "theoretically" import my data by changing the port number...doh! Anyway, I don't see any data in Solr though...and I called the import handler for over 700 documents. Ideas?

Comment: <str name="importResponse">A command is still running...</str>

Comment: Check http://solr-server:solr-port/solr/admin/schema.jsp to kinda browse around what was updated. You can see number of docs imported and number of values indexed per field to see if anything came in. If it's your first import there's probably some unexpected stuff.

Comment: And of course check the tomcat logs, somewhere like /var/log/tomcat6/catalina-out.2012-1-29.log. (EDIT: assuming you are using tomcat!)

Comment: Sadly, I'm not using Tomcat. I'll be trying to setup log4j but I don't do any java programming so... Anyway, I found this very helpful link: http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=status which can be run repeatedly and shows the status for all imports, of course. Thanks again for your help!